# Post content to Facebook through the back end

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

Using PHP, can I post content to a Facebook page when I add something to my website? In this instance I'm creating a news post on our website but want to know if Facebook is capable of receiving the same content to display on our page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Facebook php API to post on the Facebook page

```
$attachment = array(
                'message'     => '',
                'name'        => '',
                'link'        => '',
                'description' => '',
                'picture'     => "",
                'actions'     => array( array(
                    'name' => 'Get Search',
                    'link' => 'http://www.google.com'
                 ))

    );

$pageid = '';
$facebook->api('/'.$pageid .'/feed?access_token='.$facebook->getAccessToken(),'post',$attachment);
```